# How can I reconnect grpc after logic was changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, backgroundworker

I have a grpc stream to get messages. How can I reconnect grpc stream after logic was changed?

Comment: *"after logic was changed"* -- Could you expand on that? What do you mean by "logic"?

Comment: Do you mean you change the proto definition? Or the application code?